# Изменение цвета пешеходного участка линии для маршрута типа masstransport

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Пытаюсь изменить цвет линии маршрута типа masstransport c помощью опций routeActivePedestrianSegmentStrokeColor, routeStrokeColor, routeActiveStrokeColor. На получившемся маршруте участок с обещственным транспортом перекрасился, но для пешеходного участка цвет остался дефолтным. routeActivePedestrianSegmentStrokeColor и routePedestrianSegmentStrokeColor не помогают. Как быть?

```
var myRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({  
    referencePoints: [  
        point_1,  
        point_2
    ],
    params: {
        routingMode: 'masstransit',
        results: 1,
    }
}, {
    routeActivePedestrianSegmentStrokeColor: "#32c832",
    routePedestrianSegmentStrokeColor: "#32c832",
    routeStrokeColor: "#32c832",
    routeActiveStrokeColor: "#32c832",
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно писать так:

```
routeActiveWalkSegmentStrokeColor: "#00CDCD"
```

В документации это описано в разделе опций https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRoute-docpage/#multiRouter.MultiRoute__param-options